# Minecraft Custom Launcher 1.7.10 no lwggl in java.library.path

Tags: java, c#, minecraft, launcher

I'm trying to create my custom C# minecraft launcher but I have this error.
I created a `launcher.bat` file first in order to solve this problem quicker.
I have this code to start minecraft:

```
java 
-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.1\ 
-cp 
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\java3d\vecmath\1.3.1\vecmath-1.3.1.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\trove4j\trove4j\3.0.3\trove4j-3.0.3.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.5\jopt-simple-4.5.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.10.Final\netty-all-4.0.10.Final.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\15.0\guava-15.0.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.5.21\authlib-1.5.21.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.1\lwjgl-2.9.1.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.1\lwjgl_util-2.9.1.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.1\lwjgl-platform-2.9.1-natives-windows.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch\5.16\twitch-5.16.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch-platform\5.16\twitch-platform-5.16-natives-windows-64.jar;
C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch-external-platform\4.5\twitch-external-platform-4.5-natives-windows-64.jar;
net.minecraft.client.main.Main  
--username MYUSERNAME
--accessToken MYACCESSTOKEN
--version 1.7.10
--gameDir C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft 
--assetsDir C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets  
--userProperties {} 
--uuid MYUUID
```

But when i start it says `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path.`
I found on the internet that's a problem of this line

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.1\
```

But I double checked the path is correct.
Thank you in advance.

EDIT

I solved this problem easily taking out this from the arguments:

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.1\
```

And putting al the DLL's in the local folder, i can't still access them with the full path though

Comment: Actually, you should rather set the Java library path to the location of the directory containing the native libraries. Are you sure that the path you use is correct? It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the answer. I had to use the local path and not the absolute one